# Is it possible to create profile and user in apex.oracle? How?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

Is is possible to create a new and customized profile, user and tablespace in Oracle.apex (The online free tool)?

For a class that I am taking on Oracle security, I suppose to create a user in my Oracle database and give it some specific privileges. Is this something that I can do on the online version of Apex?

Thanks

Comment: You just sign up for a new workspace?

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4700:2

Comment: Yeah, I started on a new workspace. For a class that I'm taking right now, I suppose to create a user in my Oracle database and give it some specific privileges. Is it something possible on the online version of Apex?

Comment: You won't be able to do this on apex.oracle.com.  An APEX workspace is associated with a database user (schema).  System privileges are granted to this user at the time of creation.  You will not be able to issue any additional grants yourself, or seek other grants.

For all you know, you have the system privileges you need.  You can issue the following query in SQL Commands to see what is granted to you:

select * from user_sys_privs

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: FYI a great way to play around with apex and/or database is to download the Oracle-built developer virtual machines. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html